# How to get sibling folder path in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

`x`,`y`, and `z` are folders in `d:/`

`d:/x`(current)

`d:/y`

`d:/z`

What is the best way to get paths of `y` and `z` folders from given `x` folder path.

Answer (score 5):

Using pathlib module

```
In [39]: from pathlib import Path

In [40]: def get_siblings(path):
    ...:     parent = path.parent
    ...:     for x in parent.iterdir():
    ...:         if x.is_dir() and x != path:
    ...:             yield x
    ...:             

In [41]: for f in get_siblings(Path.cwd()):
    ...:     print(f)
    ...:     
/mnt
/snap
/lib
/bin
/tmp
/sbin
/usr
/lib64
/opt
/lib32
/boot
/etc
/media
```

Comment: Short answer is, get the parent and iterate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should pretty much do what you want.

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/your_path_here/'):
    print(root, "consumes", end=" ")
    print(sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files), end=" ")
    print("bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files")
```